# How can I send swift json to django server?

Tags: json, swift, django

Swift code:

```
static func send(url: URL, data: Data) async {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    let json: [String: Any] = [
        "order_details": ["meal_id":"6", "quantity":"1"],
        "restaurant_id": "1",
        "access_token": "FUJMNpU77OyuLiohOl5wzRQkGpHleV",
        "address": "13"
    ]

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    print(String(data: jsonData ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8))

    do {
        let (_, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        
        guard let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, 200..<300 ~= statusCode else {                
            throw URLError(.badURL)
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Print:

```
Optional("{\"address\":\"13\",\"order_details\":{\"quantity\":\"1\",\"meal_id\":\"6\"},\"restaurant_id\":\"1\",\"access_token\":\"FUJMNpU77OyuLiohOl5wzRQkGpHleV\"}")
```

JSON looks normal.

BUT in my django server I get this:

```
if request.method == "POST":
   print(request.POST)
```

Print:

```
<QueryDict: {'{"address":"13","order_details":{"quantity":"1","meal_id":"6"},"restaurant_id":"1","access_token":"FUJMNpU77OyuLiohOl5wzRQkGpHleV"}': ['']}>
```

i.e. my request becomes a key

I tried to compose the request in different ways, I used JSONEncoder and JSONSerializer but nothing happened

Comment: Try setting `Content-Type` using this: `request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`

Comment: it didn't work. In django server prints: `<QueryDict: {}>`